# Open dialog and close sidebar in Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

I'm developing a Google Sheets Add-on and I'm trying to have the script both close a HTML sidebar and open a dialog.

This code below doesn't work because the dialog is opened and then closed.

**HTML file**

```
google.script.run.gsSheetCreateSuccess();
google.script.host.close();
```

**.gs file**

```
function gsSheetCreateSuccess() {
var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
    ui.alert(
     'Setup Complete',
      "Success! You've Successfully completed setup on this spreadsheet.",
      ui.ButtonSet.OK)
}
```

And this code below (the reverse) doesn't work because the HTML file (the sidebar) is closed before it can execute `google.script.run.gsSheetCreateSuccess();` and open the dialog.

**HTML file**

```
google.script.host.close();
google.script.run.gsSheetCreateSuccess();
```

How can I simultaneously close the sidebar and open a dialog?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the `SuccessHandler()` of the call to `gsSheetCreateSuccess()` to close the sidebar.

```
google.script.run
             .withSuccessHandler(google.script.host.close)
             .gsSheetCreateSuccess();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.. this saved so much of googling time!